# How to relabel consul sd config to get service discovery stats based on consul metadata?

Tags: prometheus, consul, service-discovery, promql

This is how 2 services among many in consul look like:

```
    "1": {
        "ID": "1",
        "Service": "Service X",
        "Meta": {
              "country": "USA"
        },
        "Port": 0,
        "Address": "1.1.1.1",
        "Weights": {
            "Passing": 1,
            "Warning": 1
        },
        "EnableTagOverride": false
    }

    "2": {
        "ID": "2",
        "Service": "Service Y",
        "Meta": {
              "country": "CANADA"
        },
        "Port": 0,
        "Address": "2.2.2.2",
        "Weights": {
            "Passing": 1,
            "Warning": 1
        },
        "EnableTagOverride": false
    }
```

Each of these services has health checks.

My goal is to find all healthy services based on consul KV. Like, find all services that are **"passing"** in **"USA"**, or find all **"critical"** services in **"CANADA"**.

I have tried a few options, the problem I get into is that all metrics have each relabel that is mentioned in config.yaml

**QUERY 1**

`consul_health_service_status{status="passing", instance="USA"}`

**OUTPUT**

> consul_health_service_status{check="service:1",instance="USA",job="consul",node="machine",service_id="1",service_name="Service
>   X",status="passing"} 1
>
> consul_health_service_status{check="service:2",instance="USA",job="consul",node="machine",service_id="2",service_name="Service
>   Y",status="passing"} 1

**QUERY 2**

`consul_health_service_status{status="passing", instance="CANADA"}`

**OUTPUT**

> consul_health_service_status{check="service:1",instance="CANADA",job="consul",node="machine",service_id="1",service_name="Service
>   X",status="passing"} 1
>
> consul_health_service_status{check="service:2",instance="CANADA",job="consul",node="machine",service_id="2",service_name="Service
>   Y",status="passing"} 1

**CONFIG**

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'consul'
    consul_sd_configs:
      - server: 'localhost:8500'
        services: []
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_consul_service_metadata_country]
        target_label: instance
      - source_labels: ['__meta_consul_address']
        separator: ';'
        target_label:  '__address__'
        replacement: 'localhost:9107'
        action: 'replace'
```

I would loved to see an output like:

**QUERY 1**

`consul_health_service_status{status="passing", instance="USA"}`

**OUTPUT**

> consul_health_service_status{check="service:1",instance="USA",job="consul",node="machine",service_id="1",service_name="Service
>   X",status="passing"} 1

**QUERY 2**

`consul_health_service_status{status="passing", instance="CANADA"}`

**OUTPUT**

> consul_health_service_status{check="service:2",instance="CANADA",job="consul",node="machine",service_id="2",service_name="Service
>   Y",status="passing"} 1